# Dynamic list item index with Spring Form

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For decorated unordered lists like this:

```
private List<MyListItem> items = LazyList.decorate(new ArrayList(),
        FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(MyListItem.class));
```

Is it compulsory to name the attributes in the form with an index number? such as:

```
<form:input path="items[1]" />
<form:input path="items[2]" />
```

Why can't I provide the two brackets like in PHP?

```
item[]
```

Because while dynamically creating the input list with DOM would be a problem to deal with item deletions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you ask why Spring does not support a generic kind of pattern such as *item[]*, you could also be asking why your collection is not ordered according to the order of items shown by your form. Keep in mind: [java.util.List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) *is an ordered collection*, so you must tell Spring where each item in the list must be inserted.

Workaround

**1º option**

Create an AutoPopulatingList as follows

```
private List<Item> items = new AutoPopulatingList(
    new ElementFactory() {
        public Object createElement(int index) throws ElementInstantiationException {
             /**
               * Any removed item will be handled as null. 
               * So we just remove any nullable item before adding to our List
               * By using the following statement
               */
             items.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(null));

             return new Item();
        }
    });
```

**2º option**

Because Spring is open-source, you can create a custom [BeanWrapperImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.html). Behind the scenes, BeanWrapperImpl is responsible to populate your bean. Next, compile your custom Spring MVC

Answer (score -1):

You could acces your variables like:

```
<form:input path="${item[0]}" />
<form:input path="${item[1]}" />
```

Another way is:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <form:input path="${item}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: An ordered collection can use index notaton without being an array. IMO the troll detracts from your answer to this 6-month old question.

Comment: The original "Btw, php sux :p" which another SO user removed, because it's a troll. I was on mobile at the time and could not edit it myself. That's what I meant, and why I thought you were even at the level of thinking about that kind of stuff. As I said, I thought it was a good (if belated) answer, and the troll was an unnecessary distraction.